# How to encrypt in garbled circuits

Tags: multiple-encryption, garbled-circuits

I’ve read a lot of articles and a lot of questions here to understand how the encryption is done in garbled circuits. As I understand double encryption is to encrypt the gates and the truth table. The thing I wonder is how do we do that double encryption. Which method is used to generate keys?

This is what I’m talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest setting (no free XOR or point and permute) you need to use a IND-CCA encryption scheme because you need to detect decryption failures while evaluating the GC. Then double encryption is simply encrypting a message under $k_0$ to obtain some ciphertext $c_0$ and then encrypting $c_0$ again under another key $k_1$. So there are two layers of encryption. The keys must be randomly sampled from a uniform distribution for security, one key for every possible wire value.

Comment: Can you suggest one of the IND-CCA encryption schemes? I’m a beginner in cryptography so I struggle to choose one.

Comment: The general construction is encrypt then MAC (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption). There are a few combinations of what encryption scheme to use and what MAC to use, but here's a good one https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox which uses XSalsa20 and Poly1305